# laravel composer update returns RuntimeException: phpseclib

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpseclib

I have a laravel 4.1 modular system and when I try to add a package to system and update using composer's "composer update" command in console, I get the following error:

```
 [RuntimeException]
 Could not completely delete /var/www/panel.uygulamam2.com/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib, aborting.
```

Why do I get phpseclib error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the permission over `vendor` folder and make sure your current user is the owner